# Is vaping bad for exercising?

Tags: smoking

I'm considering vaping sometimes in the weekend when going out with friends. Not smoking actual cigarettes.

How bad would this for my workouts?

Comment: Are you considering starting vaping, or are you quitting smoking? Because I don't see why you would start vaping unless you're using it to step down from smoking.

Answer (score 7):

There isn’t really enough scientific data around vaping to truthfully answer. Don’t take that as an excuse to do it as that could mean it could fall anywhere on the spectrum from “Not Harmful” to “Horrible Cancer in 10 years.” Why risk it?

There simply hasn’t been enough research done to truthfully know. What IS known is that most vaping mechanisms do have nicotine. Nicotine is a highly addictive and poisonous substance. It is suspected that vaping may ultimately open the door for more people to start smoking.

The only way to be sure about the short and long term effects of vaping for your health is simply not to do it. Vaping certainly won’t help your athletic performance, so at best, it’s neutral.

Comment: There have been some reports of heavy metal toxicity from the heating elements, but again, nothing long term concrete yet.